# Format date of XPath variable in xsl for-each loop

Tags: xml, date, xslt, xpath, substring

I'm working on a simple export file and got stuck on what seems like a simple issue. The problem I'm encountering is that when I try to use substring() on a date in a for-each loop it cuts the path itself, instead of its value. If i save the value of the path as a variable and try to format it with format-date(), the export fails.

The pure value of the date I get looks like this: `2015-11-27 00:00`, and I need it to look like this:`2015-11-27` (YYYY-MM-DD).

Now I know that I'm very new to xsl so my syntax might be completly off.

Here's my code:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Person/account/transactions"><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./workplace/NUMBER"/><xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>null&#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:variable name="purchaseDate"><xsl:value-of select="./PURCHASE_DATE"/></xsl:variable><xsl:value-of select="format-date($purchaseDate,'[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')"/><xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="Person"><xsl:value-of select="./EMAIL"/><xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>982</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:for-each select="start">
        <xsl:text>"SYNCID"&#x9;"USEREMAIL"&#x9;"DATE"&#x9;"CUSTOMEREMAIL"&#x9;"SURVEYID"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The part that I'm referring to is this one, this one with format-date():
 `<xsl:variable name="purchaseDate"><xsl:value-of select="./PURCHASE_DATE"/></xsl:variable><xsl:value-of select="format-date($purchaseDate,'[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')"/>`.

I have also tried to code it this way with substring():
`<xsl:value-of select=substring("./PURCHASE_DATE", 1, 10)/>`

Comment: **1.** Could you post a **reproducible** example (XML + XSLT + expected output)? A simple example, containing only the date, would be quite sufficient. --- **2.** `format-date()` is an XSLT 2.0 function. Are you sure you are using an XSLT 2.0 processor?

Answer (score 0):

After some more intense testing I finally got this working by using substring:

```
<xsl:variable name="purchaseDate"><xsl:value-of select="./PURCHASE_DATE"/></xsl:variable><xsl:value-of select="substring($purchaseDate, 1, 10)"/>
```

Though it might not be the prettiest way of working with dates, as output I still consider it a valid workaround.

Comment: You can just do `<xsl:value-of select="substring(PURCHASE_DATE, 1, 10)"/>`. Note there should not be quote marks around `PURCHASE_DATE`, otherwise it will treat it as a literal string, rather than get the value of the element with that name.